# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`. react-router-dom v^5.2.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Running into this react router error and am confused because I've set up multiple react apps like this and have never had an issue. I ran npm update and am still having issues. It seems other people had this issue but that was with previous versions. Thanks in advance for the help!

## index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

## App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Route, Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import CompanyDetails from './pages/CompanyDetails';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import UpdateCompany from './pages/UpdateCompany';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/companies/:id/update' component={UpdateCompany} />
        <Route exact path='/companies/:id' component={CompanyDetails} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

### Errors

- index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
- Router.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging a bit I realized that my import statement:

`import { BrowserRouter as Route, Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';`

needed to be:

`import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';`

I'm not sure why the order of the import statement matters but if someone could explain it to me I would appreciate it! ✨

Comment: it is not the order of the import, in the first import you name BrowserRouter as Route, in the second you name it Router